# How to handle popup state in redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Assume I have a 'User Information' popup, 'Feeds' popup, 'Menu' popup component and some more popups on my page. If I open any popup, the remaining popups are closed. If I click outside, all of them are closed.

How do I handle popup state in redux or redux-react-local?

If I add more `document.addEventListener("click", function)`, does it affect performance?

How does event delegation work for global (document) click, keyPress, ... events?

Answer (score 1):

I would add the event handlers to each popup and have your reducers take care of changing the state accordingly. Each popup would have an ID. When a particular is clicked on, the reducer will set the state of it to open and the rest to closed.

Clicking outside could be an event handler on loss of focus. I don't think you need any global events.

Example initial state:

```
const initialState = {
    popup1: false, // closed
    popup2: false, // closed
    ...
}
```

Example reducer:

```
const { popId } = action;
case 'POPUP_CLICKED':
    const newState = { ...initialState };
    newState[popId] = true; // opened
    return { newState };

case 'POPUP_LOST_FOCUS':
    return { ...initialState };
```

Of course if you have other state attributes, don't reset the state so bluntly and iterate through, or maybe set a property called `popups` to be the state of all your popups and reset those. Either way, these set of actions should be enough to handle all edge cases.

Comment: Thanks,
I couldn't understand without global event how to close popup_lost_focus
http://jsbin.com/cipowiyoti/1/edit?css,js,console,output